# Can Amazon RDS Small do 200 timestamp updates on a primary key per second?

Tags: amazon-web-services, scalability, amazon-rds

I'm trying to get an idea of how much load a SMALL RDS instance type can handle.

I know this is highly subjective, but given that it's being done on a **primary key** and a timestamp field is being updated, the table has about 500,000 rows, will this be a problem? Assume this is the only table in the database.

If it will be a problem, what about for a large instance?

What's a reasonable estimate for how many such updates a small/large instance can handle?

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: Yes, easily.

Long answer:

- Mysql 5.5
- Innodb table with ~200k rows
- 128-bit natural primary key
- Datetime column not part of any key
- No other indexes
- Otherwise idle RDS m1.small instance
- 20x `mysql` commandlines in parallel doing `UPDATE tbl SET date='$now' WHERE pk='$key'` for different random-shuffled lists of existing primary keys

This pins the instance CPUs at 100% and mantains a steady update rate a little higher than 2000 updates per second. Write I/O ran at about 600 IOPS. Since it's CPU-bound if you're using prepared statements or batching your inserts I'm sure you can do much better before running out of CPU.